# Stop double-clicking of submit button with Javascript

Tags: javascript, onload

Here's my situation. I have a submit button. When clicked, some backend/database validation takes place and if everything's good, submit the form and disable the button so the form can't be submitted twice. If it does not pass validation, submittal cannot take place and the button stays active, so the user can resubmit the form. It sounds simple but I can't make it work. This is a C# web application.

I have tried to add the code to the button on page load. When the submit button is clicked and if validation fails, remove the code that disables the button. But here is my problem. Since the "disable" code is removed and the user fixes any error and resubmit, the button can be clicked more than one as the code is no longer there.

I do not want to use Ajax for this because the backend check is very complicated. Is there another way to do it? I've tried to add the "disable" code on "load" but it does not work on post back when the validation fails.

```
 if (window.addEventListener)
        window.addEventListener("load", lockSubmit, false);
    else if (window.attachEvent)
        window.attachEvent("onload", lockSubmit);
    else window.onload = lockSubmit;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show lockSubmit code

Comment: Can you be more precise? Please create a fiddle to support your question.

Comment: If you won't use Ajax you shouldn't bother with JavaScript at all. Why would you disable the button if the form was successfully submitted - just don't show it again; show a message on success or give them a form back to submit it again on error - that's it.

Comment: @hex494D49, even though the form was successfully submitted, it takes a long time to process and some users click on the button again. I already have a throbber but some still click the button. Now I need to disable it.

Comment: Check the answer below and let me know if you found it useful

Answer (score 1):

Try the snippet below

```
window.onload = function(){

  // Insert the following function somewhere in your .js file / section
  (function prevent_over_submitting(){
    var form = document.forms.theform;
    if(form || form.nodeName == 'FORM'){
      form.onsubmit = function(){
        form.submit.value = 'Proccesing...';
        form.submit.disabled = true;
      };
    }
  })();

};
```

While your form should look something like this one

```
<form id="theform" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="firsname" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="" />  
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />  
</form>
```

Here is a working [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/kegemoya/1/edit?html,js,output) so you can play around.

---

Update:

The logic behind the snippet above

```
// server-side code (rather in pseudo-code this time)
if(form_has_been_submitted){               // check if the form has been submitted
    errors[] = validate_data(post_data);   // call the method to validate data
    if(errors_array_is_empty){             // if everything is fine
        submit_data();                     // submit data
        redirect_or_do_something;          // (maybe) do other things           
    }                                      // otherwise don't do anything
}

// validation method
validate_data(post){ // the only argument here represents all your form data
    error = array;
    if(post['firstname'] == wrong){  // check for error 
        error['firstname'] = 'Check your firsname'; // if you found one, push it to the error array
    }
    if(post['lastname'] == wrong){   // the same as in previous case
        error['lastname'] = 'Check your lastname'; // the same as in previous case
    }
    return error; // return that array, it might be full or empty
}

// client-side code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyApplication</title>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      // the JavaScript snippet from above 
  </script>

</head>
<body>

    <form id="theform" method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="firsname" value="" />
        <!-- show the error if you found one, otherwise show an empty string -->
        <span><% (error['firstname'] ? error['firstname'] : "") %></span>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" value="" />
        <!-- same as in the previous case -->
        <span><% (error['lastname'] ? error['lastname'] : "") %></span>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />  
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the JavaScript snippet above only disables the submit button onclick to prevent over-submitting; it will be enabled once the page is loaded again. This isn't my favorite way of validation but I followed your logic.

Comment: I need to do some backend validation first and only when it passes, I submit the form and disable the button. If validation does not pass, I can't disable the button.

Comment: @LacHo You're mixing things ;) form.submit means start-processing-form-data and not submit-data-to-database You may validate data on client using JavaScript, on server using C# (in your case) or you can combine both methods - a) validate on client using JavaScript and then validate them again on server (since client validation isn't secure or b) don't validate on client, only send form data by JavaScript (Ajax), validate them on server and send a feedback. I prefer the last one. Since you said you won't do this with JavaScript the snippet above is the best solution. Check the updated answer.

Comment: I think you're right. I'm mixing things and it's best to do Ajax. It's just that I need to pass to the service method a big object and that does not work. I have to come up with another way to send the object. Thanks for the code and jsBin!

Comment: @LacHo Are you submitting binary files or just textual data? If you want to use JavaScript let me know, I'll show you the logic. Anyhow, if you need any further assistance, just drop me a note here ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can add this code in the onclick function:

First, add a global javascript variable, say `var click = false`;

and add this condition before validation occurs:

```
if(click){
    return false
} else {
    your normal validation code
}
```

if your page reloads each time you submit, then there is no need to add anything further, but if doesn't then add `setInterval` method which will reset the click variable for next use if validation fails.

The state of the click variable will remain true after first click and will further stop multiple clicks, unless page reloads or we reset the variable manually through code.

Comment: I get that your response is valid and provides a working answer to the OPs question - but this is now 5+ years old - was there really a need to bump such an old thread?